# Java Spring Update Record URL

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I'm making a library project in Spring, containing details about books (name, author,price). I can add new books but when trying to update a record stored in H2 In-memory Database, via below URL I get error 404. See my update code below, am I going wrong code wise or URL wise?

URL: localhost:8080/books/4 -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"Test Book\",\"author\":\"James\",\"price\":\"9.99\"}"

```
'''
@Autowired
private BookRepo repo;

@PutMapping("/books/{id}")
Book saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody Book myBook, @PathVariable Long id) {

    return repo.findById(id)
            .map(x -> {
                x.setName(myBook.getName());
                x.setAuthor(myBook.getAuthor());
                x.setPrice(myBook.getPrice());
                return repo.save(x);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Book.setId(id);
                return repo.save(myBook);
            });
}
```

````
***BookRepo.java
public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

}```
````

Comment: any exception on stack trace?

Comment: is x!=null? Did you tried debugging the code?